# Meteorjs use input select multiple and push to collections

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

Hi everybody this is my first project in meteor js.
I'm using Meteor 1.4.1.1 with this package:

```
aldeed:collection2               2.10.0
```

I have this field in my collection

```
Clienti.ClienteSchema = new SimpleSchema({
cantieri: {
        type: [Clienti.Cantieri],
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
}
});

Clienti.Cantieri = new SimpleSchema({
    giorni: {
        type: [Clienti.Giorni],
        optional: true,
        autoform: {
            type: "hidden"
        }
    }
});

Clienti.Giorni = new SimpleSchema({
 giorno: {
   type: Date,
   label: "giorno del lavoro"
 },
 oraPartenza: {
   type: Date,
   label: 'Giorno e ora partenza',
 },
 oraInizio: {
   type: Date,
   label: 'Giorno e ora inizio',
   optional: true
 },
 oraFine: {
   type: Date,
   label: 'Giorno e ora fine',
   optional: true
 },
 dipendenti: {
   type: [Dipendenti]
 }
});
```

This is the input's select

```
<div class="col-xs-12">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="checkbox" for=dipendenti>dipendenti</label>
        <select multiple name="dipendenti">
            {{#each Dipendenti}}
                <option value="{{_id}}">{{nome}}  {{cognome}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

with this form I'd like to submit the last field Giorni in a existing Cliente.cantiere.

I tried:

```
Template.nuovoGiorno.events({
    'submit #Giorno'(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
        const target = event.target;
        const giorno = target.giorno.value;
        const oraPartenza = target.oraPartenza.value;
        let select = target.dipendenti.options;
        let selezionati=[];
        for (var i = 0; i < select.length; i++) {
            var option = select[i];
            if (option.selected){
                console.log(id);
                console.log('opzione  ' + option.value);
                Clienti.update({_id:id}, {$set:{
                'cantieri.giorni.giorno': giorno,
                'cantieri.giorni.oraPartenza': oraPartenza,
                'cantieri.giorni.dipendenti._id': option.value
                }});
            }
        }
    }
});
```

but doesn't work. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `cantieri` key is an array of objects which are themselves arrays of objects. Is this really what you want?

I would try:

```
Clienti.update({ _id: id }, { $set: {
  cantieri: [{
    giorni: [{
      giorno: giorno,
      oraPartenza: oraPartenza,
      dipendenti._id: option.value
    }]
  }]
}});
```

If you want to push a `giorni` into a specific `cantieri` (as per your comment) then select the `cantieri` you want in the query and then push a new `giorni` into it:

```
Clienti.update({ _id: id, cantieri: myCantieri }, { $push: { 'cantieri.giorni': newGiorni }});
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer!  yes i want an array because collection's Clienti can has many cantieri. But now how push giorni in a specific cantieri? it is possible?

Comment: i tried so:
`aggiungiGiorno: function(id,idC,doc,){
  Clienti.update({ _id: id, "cantieri._id": idC },{ $push: { 
   "cantieri.giorni": 
   doc.giorno,
         oraPartenza: doc.oraPartenza,
         dipendenti: doc.dipendenti}
  });    
 }`
but doesn'work and the console log not retunr nothing.

Comment: That's not a valid update. You're pushing an _object_ so you need `Clienti.update({ _id: id, "cantieri._id": idC },{ $push: { "cantieri.giorni": object }})`

Comment: this the object that i pass at method how doc
`let nuovoGiorno = {
    giorno: $('[name=giorno]').val(),
    oraPartenza: $('[name=oraPartenza]').val(),
    dipendenti: [],
   }`,
and this is the method
`aggiungiGiorno: function(id,idC,doc,){
  Clienti.update({ _id: id, "cantieri._id": idC },{ $push: { 
   "cantieri.giorni": doc}
  });
 }`
i submit the form and the console.log not return nothing. But the cantiere is not updated.